# Using @value in javadoc with a data.properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

I'm using Javadoc for documentation. Currently I have something that looks like this

```
/**
* Test Doco
*
*/
public class testClass() {
    public void testMethod() {
        /** More test doco
        */

        customFunction() 
    }
}
```

I also have a data.properties file that is pretty straight forward:

```
basic.entry=test
second.entry=test2
third.entry=test3
```

I was wondering if there was a way to link my Javadoc to pull a value out of the data.properties file?

I have tried:

```
/** 
* {@value /properties/data.properties#basic.entry)
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither JavaDoc specification nor IntelliJ IDEA support values from external files.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write your own JavaDoc pre-processor to scan through your code for special tags and insert the values from whatever files they reference, or whatever else you need, as valid JavaDoc comments, and then run the JavaDoc tool against your code.
Example:

```
/**
* The values from the file are:
*/
//[filetocsv /properties/data.properties#basic.entry]
```

Your preprocessor could read the file, generate the values you want and replace everything after the 1st line (or whatever) of the JavaDoc immediately above with these, something like this:

```
/**
* The values from the file are:
* basic.entry=test,
* second.entry=test2,
* third.entry=test3
*/
//[filetocsv /properties/data.properties#basic.entry]
```

and now JavaDoc can scan your code and genenerate the HTML docs.
Pretty simple.  Not much work needed to do this.